# How to add row dynamically in table layout or How to show full db Records in single table Layout

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-tablelayout

Hello Techie :) i am new to android . i'm developing one app where user is registering with all personal detail and mobile device detail and after user login all the things working fine and met with result but when **i'm moving to admin section** here i have issue and i'm not getting any idea about this .

**Parts of Admin section where i am stuck  :-** 
1) after admin login , all table records should be shown in one table layout here u can say i want to populate all table records in Table Layout .

i try with specific user name and its showing in the table layout but it's not my requirement , i have to show all users in Table layout .

i'm sharing my code here , will u all suggest me what to do next and how can i achieve my requirement. 
Thanks for your valuable time :)

//MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp;
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.Intent; import android.os.Build; import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources; import android.telephony.TelephonyManager; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.Toast;

    /**  * Created by yadapras on 6/26/2016.  */ public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        EditText a,b;
        String usr,pass;
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

        public void onButtonClick(View v)
        {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.BLogin)
            {
                a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
                usr = a.getText().toString();
                b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
                pass = b.getText().toString();



                String password = null;

                if( a.getText().toString().length() == 0 || usr == "" || usr == null)
                    a.setError( " User name is required!" );
                if( b.getText().toString().length() == 0 || pass =="" || pass == null)
                    b.setError( "Password is required!" );
                else{
                    password = helper.searchPass(usr);
                }

               if (a.getText().toString().equals("admin") && b.getText().toString().equals("admin"))
               {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminDisplay.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
               }else{
                   if (pass.equals(password) && password != null) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmpDetail.class);
                       intent.putExtra("usr", usr);

                       TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                       String uid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                       String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER; // Not used in current scenario
                       String model = Build.MODEL;
                       int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                       String versionRelease = Build.VERSION.RELEASE; // not used in current scenario
                       String msg = "IMEI No: " + uid + "\n" + "Manufacturer is :" + manufacturer + "\n" + "Model is :" + model + "\n" + "Os Version is :" + version + "\n" + "VersionRelease is :" + versionRelease;
                       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                       toast.show();

                       Register r = new Register();
                       r.setImei_no(uid);
                       r.setDev_model(model);
                       r.setOs_version(version);
                       r.setUname(usr);

                       helper.updateTable(r); /*For updating table with new Coloumn*/

                       startActivity(intent);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Toast err_pass = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"UserName and Password don't Match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                       err_pass.show();
                   }
               }


            }
            if (v.getId() == R.id.BSignup)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registration.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    }
```

//DatabaseHelper.java

```
    package com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.ArrayMap;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by yadapras on 7/8/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "registrationDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "registrations";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD= "password";
    public static final String COLUMN_RE_PASSWORD= "re_password";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME= "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL= "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE_NO= "phone_no";

    /*Adding three coloumn IMEI_NO,OS_Version,Model_Device Respectively*/

    public static final String COLUMN_IMEI_NO = "imei_no";
    public static final String COLUMN_DEV_MODEL = "dev_model";
    public static final String COLUMN_OS_VERSION = "os_version";


    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table registrations(id integer primary key not null, " +
            "username text not null, password text not null, re_password text not null, name text not null, email text not null," +
            "phone_no number not null,imei_no text, dev_model text, os_version text);";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.sqLiteDatabase=sqLiteDatabase;
        Log.d("#####Table Value",TABLE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME ;
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void registerUser(Register r) {
        /*Inserting anything in to the dataBase make sure it should be writable*/
        sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from registrations";
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();

        Log.d("##count",""+count);
        values.put(COLUMN_ID,count);
        Log.d("##id",r.getUname());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME,r.getUname());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,r.getPassword());
        values.put(COLUMN_RE_PASSWORD,r.getRe_password());
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME,r.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, r.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_PHONE_NO, r.getPhone_no());

        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,values); /*this will insert Register object in to the Database*/

        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

    public String searchPass(String usr) {
        sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select username,password from "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
         String a,b ; // a and b will be userName and Password respectively
        b = "Not Found";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                a = cursor.getString(0);
                Log.d("##username from db",a);
                if (a.equals(usr))
                {
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return b;
    }

    public JSONObject showDetail(String usr) {
        sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query ="SELECT * FROM  registrations   where username='"+usr+"'" ;//"select * from registrations where username = p";
      //  String  query = "SELECT * FROM registrations";
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {

                int columnsQty = cursor.getColumnCount();
                Log.d("###count-->", String.valueOf(columnsQty));
                for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                    try {
                        data.put(cursor.getColumnName(idx),cursor.getString(idx));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("###Data Value",data.toString());
        return data;
    }

    public void updateTable(Register r) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_IMEI_NO,r.getImei_no());
        Log.d("###Column_IMEI_NO",r.getImei_no());
        cv.put(COLUMN_DEV_MODEL,r.getDev_model());
        cv.put(COLUMN_OS_VERSION,r.getOs_version());
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,cv,"username = ?",new String[]{r.getUname()});; /*Working for all fields*/

            /*SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(COLUMN_IMEI_NO,r.getImei_no());
            Log.d("###Column_IMEI_NO",r.getImei_no());
            cv.put(COLUMN_DEV_MODEL,r.getDev_model());
            cv.put(COLUMN_OS_VERSION,r.getOs_version());
            String updateQuery = "Update registrations set " + COLUMN_IMEI_NO + " = '"+ r.getImei_no() +"' where " + COLUMN_USERNAME + "="+"'"+ r.getUname() +"'";
            db.execSQL(updateQuery);
            db.close();*/
    }

}
```

//AdminDisplay.java

```
    package com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;

public class AdminDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {


    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    TextView id,name,email,mobileno,imei_no,dev_model ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_display);
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1) ;
        id = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_id);
        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.admin_Uname);
        email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_email);
        mobileno = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_phone);
        imei_no = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_imeiNo);
        dev_model = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_dev_model);

        JSONObject details = helper.showDetail("pcu9044"); // ***Here i'm trying registered user so i'm getting only this user field in TableLayout .***

        for (int i=0; i<details.length();i++){
            TableRow row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);

            try {
                table.removeView(row);
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_id)).setText(details.getString("id"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_email)).setText(details.getString("email"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_Uname)).setText(details.getString("name"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_phone)).setText(details.getString("phone_no"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_imeiNo)).setText(details.getString("imei_no"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_dev_model)).setText(details.getString("dev_model"));
                table.addView(row);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

i'm attaching screen shot of my output, if yup people have nay doubt please feel free to ask . Thank u in advance .

[Result output with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv3Fj.png)

Comment: Did you think in using ListView or RecyclerView to show your data?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez but we cnt show full table records in list view ?? i dont have much idea about this

Comment: Inside the listview or recycler view you can inflate another view with as much textviews as you want, so you can show all your full table record. Do you need an example?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez yeah :) ur help is appreciated

Comment: Check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html and tell me if you have any doubt

Comment: An also check this one that I think fix better with your needs: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156

Comment: @MiguelBenitez please see my answer if its correct please mark correct and up vote to my question if it helps to others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Techie :) I solved my problem after reading many articles on Table Layout over Internet. i'm giving this problems solution with Table-Layout hope this will help others .

## AdminDisplay.java  # Editable Version

```
     package com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.JsonReader;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TableLayout;
    import android.widget.TableRow;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class AdminDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        TableLayout tableLayout;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        private Context context ;
    
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.admin_display);
            context = this;
            DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    
            tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1) ;
            TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow(context);
            rowHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c0c0c0"));
            rowHeader.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            String[] headerText={"ID","USERNAME","EMAIL","PHONE_NO","IMEI_NO","DEV_MODEL"};
    
            for(String c:headerText) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(18);
                tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                tv.setText(c);
    
                rowHeader.addView(tv);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(rowHeader);
    
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
    
            try
            {
                String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME;
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
                if(cursor.getCount() >0)
                {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        // Read columns data
                        int id          = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                        String user_name= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("username"));
                        String email= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
                        String phone_no = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phone_no"));
                        String imei_no = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imei_no"));
                        String dev_model = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dev_model"));
    
                        // dara rows
                        TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
                        row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        String[] colText={id+"",user_name,email,phone_no,imei_no,dev_model};
                        for(String text:colText) {
                            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                            tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tv.setTextSize(16);
                            tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    
                            tv.setText(text);
                            row.addView(tv);
                        }
                        tableLayout.addView(row);
    
                    }
    
                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    
            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
    
            }
            finally
            {
                db.endTransaction();
                // End the transaction.
                db.close();
                // Close database
            }
    
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem that I see here is that when you say:

> "i try with specific user name and its showing in the table layout but
>   it's not my requirement , i have to show all users in Table layout".

By searching for one single user from the database, you are only retrieving a single record in the database that is associated with the username you are searching for. Your method `helper.showDetail()` returns a single JSONObject - this object corresponds to the record in the database where username = pcu9044.

If I am understanding your situation correctly, you need to call a method that selects ALL of the records from the database in order to display what you want on the screen.  Your `helper.showDetail()` will be a good start, but you can modify code slightly to achieve what you'd like.

I would recommend using either a list or array of JSONObjects instead of a single JSONObject.  Initialize your data structure before you enter the `if (cursor.moveToFirst())` conditional (like you have it now), but within each iteration of the loop, you create a new object, fill it with what the cursor returns for that row, and then add it to the structure.  The code would look something like this:

```
public JSONArray showDetail() {
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query ="SELECT * FROM  registrations";// * THIS WILL RETURN ALL RECORDS IN REGISTRATIONS
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
    //JSONObject data = new JSONObject(); *change this to an array
    JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {

            int columnsQty = cursor.getColumnCount();
            Log.d("###count-->", String.valueOf(columnsQty));

            // Must create a new object each time you iterate to a new row to add to the array
            JSONObject record = new JSONObject();

            for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                try {
                    // Fill the object
                    record.put(cursor.getColumnName(idx),cursor.getString(idx));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            // Add the object to the array and repeat
            data.put(record);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("###Data Value",data.toString());
    return data;
}
```

If you do it this way, your `helper.showDetail()` will return an array filled with objects that each symbolize a row.  From there, your `AdminDisplay.java` should then cycle through the array, grab each object, and fill a new row with the information you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thks for your Valuable time and idea its help's me :) but i solved my problem in different way and i give my questions answer please visit ones, please mark if its correct and give vote for my question if it will helps to others :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `table.removeView(row);` from the loop, if not you will get only one row at the end of the loop as it removes the previous row when a new row is added

```
 for (int i=0; i<details.length();i++){
            TableRow row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);

            try {

                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_id)).setText(details.getString("id"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_email)).setText(details.getString("email"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_Uname)).setText(details.getString("name"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_phone)).setText(details.getString("phone_no"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_imeiNo)).setText(details.getString("imei_no"));
                ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.admin_usr_dev_model)).setText(details.getString("dev_model"));
                table.addView(row);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: i want to show full db records in single Table Layout . i m doing only for one reg user will u help me out plzz look in this line --->

JSONObject details = helper.showDetail("pcu9044"); // ***Here i'm trying registered user so i'm getting only this user field in TableLayout .***

Comment: please see my answer if its correct plz mark as a correct and if its useful to other please do upVote for my question Thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this method i have just updated a method of your code, You can replace with your own method by.
Valiable **isAdmin** is true when admin get detail and false when user.

```
public JSONObject showDetail(String usr, boolean isAdmin)
{
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "";
    if (isAdmin)
        query = "SELECT * FROM registrations";
    else
        query ="SELECT * FROM  registrations   where username='"+usr+"'" ;//"select * from registrations where username = p";

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {

            int columnsQty = cursor.getColumnCount();
            Log.d("###count-->", String.valueOf(columnsQty));
            for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                try {
                    data.put(cursor.getColumnName(idx),cursor.getString(idx));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("###Data Value",data.toString());
    return data;
}
```

It may help you and Let me know if any query you have.